# How to open a task module in Teams Bot without using BotFramework (Python)

Tags: python-3.x, microsoft-teams

Currently, I am developing a Teams Bot in Python (Flask). Due to certain circumstances, I am proceeding with bot development without using BotFramework. I have been able to return an AdaptiveCard based on user messages.

However, when I press the button inside the AdaptiveCard, I encounter errors or end up in a state similar to the image below within the task module.

```
{"error":{"code":"BadArgument","message":"Unknown activity type"}}
```

[TaskModule image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/co3YY.png)

I will also provide the Python code I am currently writing. I suspect that the issue lies in the JSON, but I'm not sure. I'm in a bit of a dilemma. I would appreciate any advice you can provide. Thank you in advance.

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
import requests
import json
import os
from threading import Thread
MICROSOFT_TENANT_ID = "********************************"
MICROSOFT_CLIENT_ID = "********************************"
MICROSOFT_CLIENT_SECRET = "********************************"

app = Flask(__name__)

def fetch_access_token():
    token_url = f"https://login.microsoftonline.com/botframework.com/oauth2/v2.0/token"
    payload = {
        'grant_type': 'client_credentials',
        'client_id': MICROSOFT_CLIENT_ID,
        'client_secret': MICROSOFT_CLIENT_SECRET,
        'scope': 'https://api.botframework.com/.default',
    }
    headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
}

    
    response = requests.post(token_url,headers=headers, data=payload)
    # print(response.text)
    access_token = json.loads(response.text)['access_token']

    return access_token

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return 'It works!'

@app.route('/message', methods=['POST'])
def webhook():
    json_body = request.get_json()
    print(f"Parameter: {json_body}")
    if json_body['type'] == 'invoke':
        Thread(target=create_task_module_response, args=(json_body,)).start()

    if json_body['type'] == 'message':
        Thread(target=process_message, args=(json_body,)).start()
    


    # HTTP 200 OKならなんでもよい
    return jsonify(status=200)

def process_message(params):
    service_url = params['serviceUrl']
    conversation_id = params['conversation']['id']
    access_token = fetch_access_token()
    print(params)
    try:
        if params['text'] == 'aa':
            reply = { 
                "type": "message",
                "text": f"Reply for {params['text']}"
            }

        elif params['text'] == 'test':


            # メッセージにアクションを追加
            reply = {
                "type": "message",
                "attachments": [
                    {
                        "contentType": "application/vnd.microsoft.card.adaptive",
                        "content": {
            "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
            "version": "1.5",
            "type": "AdaptiveCard",
            "body": [
                {
                    "type": "TextBlock",
                    "text": "Task Module Invocation from Adaptive Card",
                    "weight": "Bolder",
                    "size": 3
                }
            ],
            "actions": [
                {
                    "type": "Action.Submit",
                    "title": "Adaptive Card",
                    "data": {
                        "msteams": {
                            "type": "task/fetch",
                            "body": {
                "type": "task/fetch",
                "title": "Open Task Module",
                "value": {
                    "type": "AdaptiveCard",
                    "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
                    "version": "1.0",
                    "body": [
                        {
                            "type": "TextBlock",
                            "text": "こんにちは",
                            "weight": "bolder",
                            "size": "large"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
                        },
                        "data": "AdaptiveCard"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "type": "Action.Submit",
                    "title": "Custom Form",
                    "data": {
                        "msteams": {
                            "type": "task/fetch"
                        },
                        "data": "CustomForm"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "type": "Action.Submit",
                    "title": "YouTube",
                    "data": {
                        "msteams": {
                            "type": "task/fetch"
                        },
                        "data": "YouTube"
                    }
        }
    ]
}
                    }
                ]
            }


    except KeyError:
            print("module★")
            reply = {
                "type": "task/fetch",
                "title": "Open Task Module",
                "value": {
                    "type": "AdaptiveCard",
                    "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
                    "version": "1.0",
                    "body": [
                        {
                            "type": "TextBlock",
                            "text": "こんにちは",
                            "weight": "bolder",
                            "size": "large"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }





    headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': f"Bearer {access_token}"
    }
    res = requests.post(f"{service_url}v3/conversations/{conversation_id}/activities", json=reply, headers=headers)
    print(res.text)
    return res
    # print("Response Body:", response.status_code)
    # print("Response Headers:", response.text)

def create_task_module_response(params):
    print('★★★★★★')
    service_url = params['serviceUrl']
    conversation_id = params['conversation']['id']
    access_token = fetch_access_token()


    reply = {
  "type": "invoke",
  "name": "task/fetch",
  "value": {
    "title": "タスク モジュールのタイトル",
    "height": 400,
    "width": 500,
  }
}



    headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': f"Bearer {access_token}"
    }




    resp =requests.post(f"{service_url}v3/conversations/{conversation_id}/activities", json=reply, headers=headers)
    print(resp.text)
    return resp
    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: Are you getting error while opening the task module? Looks like you are trying to show adaptive card on Task module. Please verify your Card Json once and check if it's working without nesting the card.

Comment: Thank you for your advice!


 Yes. When I open the task module, an error message is displayed inside the task module. No errors are reported on the Python side.



 I will try that. The JSON of the card that I am trying to display inside the task module can be sent in a message, and the format should be correct.